# Easier C++ STL iterator instantiation

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to syntactically shorten/simplify iterator declarations in C++. Normally I would:

```
vector<pair<string, int> > v;
vector<pair<string, int> >::iterator i;
```

I was hoping for some magic that would:

```
vector<pair<string, int> > v;
magic v::iterator i;
```

Comment: If using C++ 11, check the `auto` specifier.

Comment: If you're using C++11, just say `auto i(v.begin());` and the compiler will infer the correct type for `i`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you have three options:

**1. Typedef the vector instantiation**

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> Vp;
Vp v;
Vp::iterator i;
```

**2. Use `decltype`**

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> v;
decltype(v)::iterator i;
```

**3. Use `auto`**

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> v;
auto i = v.begin();
```

I'd say the third option is the most common, idiomatic usage, but all are valid, and the first option works in C++98, too.

Comment: The decltype was the magic i was looking for. Pity only in C++11 though.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `typedef` for aliasing your `vector<pair<string, int> >`

```
typedef vector<pair<string, int> > Vp; // vector of pair
```

And then,

```
Vp v;

Vp::iterator i;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use typedefs a lot:

```
// vector of strings
typedef std::vector<std::string> str_vec;

// iterator
typedef str_vec::iterator str_vec_iter;

// constant iterator
typedef str_vec::const_iterator str_vec_citer;

// reverse iterator
typedef str_vec::reverse_iterator str_vec_riter;

// constant reverse iterator
typedef str_vec::const_reverse_iterator str_vec_criter

int main()
{
    str_vec v = {"a", "b", "c"};

    // writable iteration
    for(str_vec_iter i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        i->append("!");

    // constant iteration
    for(str_vec_citer i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';

    // constant reverse iteration
    for(str_vec_criter i = v.rbegin(); i != v.rend(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

Certain containers are so common that I have their typedefs in personal header files that I use all the time (namespaced naturally).

But since C++11 its not so important because of the `auto` keyword that deduces the type for you:

```
for(auto&& i: v)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can write:

```
decltype(v)::iterator
```

Answer (score 0):

**C++ 11:**

```
using v = vector<pair<string, int> >;
using i = v::iterator;
```

***Magic:***

```
v _v;
i _i{ _v.begin( ) };
```